# What is the best distance glider that can carry a 200 lb load?

Tags: glider, flight-dynamics, unpowered

Good morning, I'm an emigrant from Worldbuilding and I ask this first question in part to help me discover what I don't know I don't know.

My definition of best: Longest recorded single flight time with closest to maximum load. I might be misusing some terms, but I'd prefer design that itself was 100lbs or less and could still carry 200 additional lbs (90kg).

I think I used appropriate tags but feel free to provide suggestions and requests for more information.

Comment: You're asking "how far can a glider that weighs less than 100 lbs and can carry 200 lbs fly"?

Comment: Launched from what height? What kind of atmospheric conditions? Are there mountains or other terrain nearby to take advantages of updrafts? Localized weather? There are too many variables to say that a glider weighing X can go Y distance, gliders don't just descend, you can climb in a glider too, to [over 50,000 feet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perlan_Project).

Comment: @DanPichelman Sorta. I want to see what the glider that can fly the farthest with 200 lbs looks like and how it is built.

Comment: @RonBeyer My definition of best includes 'longest recorded single flight'. So the longest flight that actually happened and was recorded by a glider that was less than 100 lbs. That would probably require the ideal situation.

Comment: It would very much depend on weather conditions (updrafts) and pilot skill.

Comment: Kind of like this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hang_gliding  There are 2-place hang gliders, so that meets your 200 additional pounds criterion.

Comment: best glide slope donnot depend on the weight (but the speed at which you can glide near to this best glide slope do depend on weight).

Comment: Google "tandem hang glider" and "tandem hang glider record distance".  Not sure whether any one actually keeps distance records for tandem hang gliding flights or not.  However  the truth is that many long distance hang gliding flights have been set with a payload of over 200 pounds if you consider combined weight of pilot, harness, parachute, helmet, instruments-- this stuff probably almost always adds up to more than 30-40 pounds over pilot body weight.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hang gliders weigh less than 100lbs and some can carry 200lbs.

The FAI distance record is 475 miles and must have taken hours to accomplish.  Note that the distance is measured as a point-to-point distance, not as actual ground track distance.  Unpowered airplanes require lift to stay aloft and must circle in rising colums of air to gain altitude.  The 475 mile record may have required a significantly larger number of ground track miles to achieve.

There are generally two ways to gain altitude:

First, find a rising column of air (thermal).  This is as simple as flying in a straight line until you feel a wing rise (indicating lift).  Turn INto the lift and continue to circle until you stop climbing.  Youtube has many examples of this.

Second, ascend into a lee wave.  A decent wave will get you >30,000' from which you can set out in search of thermals or more waves.  Bring oxygen.

Both of these require the glider to be towed aloft or launched from a higher elevation (ex. a mountain).

Comment: This answer would be improved by adding a section about ridge soaring, and deleting or modifying the section about lee waves.  Hang gliders almost never fly in lee waves because the wind and potential turbulence is typically just too strong for them.  Also each individual sentence or paragraph is a little unclear as to whether you are referring to hang gliders, sailplanes, or both.  This answer could be greatly improved with just a little work.

Answer (score 2):

To improve performance over that of conventional hang gliders, you need a rigid wing. [Here](http://www.lightsportaircraftpilot.com) is a directory of light sport aircraft; there are quite a few which weigh 100 lbs empty or less. My recommendation would be the [Swift lite](http://www.aeriane.com/products/aircrafts/swift/swiftlight/), a development of the [Swift foot launched glider](http://aero.stanford.edu/Reports/SWIFTArticle1991.html). Yes, at 48 kg it busts your limit of 100 lbs, but not by much.

[image: Swift hang glider in flight]

Swift foot launched hang glider in flight (picture [source](http://aero.stanford.edu/Reports/images/SWIFT1.jpg))

[Here](http://aero.stanford.edu/Reports/SWIFTAIAA004336.pdf) is a more detailed description. The Swift is so much better than conventional hang gliders that it has been banished from competitions and placed in a separate class. A two-seater version has also been developed; this should be capable of carrying a 200 lbs payload in addition to the pilot.